# Latest time for morning Sh’ma

Tags: halacha, time, zemanim, leniencies, morning-day

What are the opinions for the absolute LATEST time for reciting the morning Sh’ma B’dieved, not  l’chatchila. Obviously there are different opinions for what is the latest or not but what are they. Sources appreciated please

Comment: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kriyat_Shema#Latest_time

Comment: Are there different opinions for the latest possible opinion? That doesn't make sense. There's by definition only one latest opinion and you may or may not want to rely on it.

Comment: There's only one time for the latest time to say shema which is by the end of the 3rd hour. The only variation for this being later or earlier would depend on how hours are calculated but the rule for when shema is said is still the same.

Comment: @Dude some rishonim hold it's the beginning of the third hour not the end of it (ie the end of the second hour). Also many rishonim hold that time is the bedieved time but the correct time is only before sunrise.

Comment: Yes but my point is this is the latest time. There aren't any shitas which put it at a later hour

Comment: @Dude Some hold the third hour time is rabbinic and the biblical time lasts all day.